# OperationalError in Django app: models.py

Tags: python, django

There's an OperationalError in my models.py code.
Can anyone pinpoint the problem?
I have tried deleting the cache (along with previous migrations) and doing them over -
doesn't help the issue.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A post within a blog."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of a model."""
        return self.text

class Post(models.Model):
    """Class for Blog Post entries."""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

It gives me the following errors, if this helps:

```
OperationalError at /admin/blogs/post/
no such table: blogs_post
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from blogs.models import Topic, Post

admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(Post)
```

Comment: Please add the error traceback that Django is giving you.

Comment: Are you doing `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes to both @JohnGordon

Comment: @quinoabrah also post your admin.py. Most probably you wrote something there that does not exist

Comment: What lead to the error? Did you change any class names in your models.py?

Comment: Yes. @almostabeginner

Comment: Done. @JahongirRahmonov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed a class name, then you probably have objects with the old class name that the migration can't find the table for.

Delete the `db.sqlite3` file at project folder. Delete all previous migrations. Then `makemigrations` then `migrate`. This basically resets everything and deletes all the objects. You have to recreate your Superuser afterwards also.

Hope this helps,.